# Conditional Formatting - Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Community, I have a pretty simple problem today.  I'm pretty new at Excel formatting.  Anyways, I have a box that is going to change the font color of a box from white to black if a condition is true.  There are technically two conditions and I think the way I set one of the conditions is wrong anyways.

```
=NOT($K$4="") //first condition, if box K4 != blank (works)
=NOT($K$4="No") //second condition, if box K4 != No (does not work)
```

Is there a way to combine those two and if so how?  Secondly, if not, am I writing the second condition properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily discard the `NOT()` and use `AND()` to combine two conditions:

```
=AND($K$4<>"", $K$4<>"No")
```

If `K4` is neither blank nor contains `No`, then format (in other words, don't format if `K4` is blank or contains 'No').

`<>` means 'not equal to' in excel formulae.